# How to display currency in Indian numbering format

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I am trying to generate the numbers in Indian currency format
example the output value like 550500 should  display as 5,50,500.

Below is my script.

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6absz1xx/2/)

```
   $("#rTpe1").click(function(e){
      $("#rFor1").val(this.value * $("#PerHourRate1").val());
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate numbers in Indian currency format,  you can use `toLocaleString('en-IN')`. You need to change the input type of `rFor1` to text.

Also, if it helps you can use `keyup` event instead of `click`.

```
<input  name="" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"value="0" id="rFor1" readonly>

$("#rTpe1").keyup(function(e){
   $("#rFor1").val((this.value * $("#PerHourRate1").val()).toLocaleString('en-IN'));
});
```

Comment: keyup?  How does that assist when other object values are used?  It might not even by a focus-able/key-able element.

Comment: Thanks Ritz
Do I need to use toLocaleString('en-IN') to genrate SUM 
Example Now i am using ....$("#rFor3").val( Number($("#rFor1").val()) + Number($("#rFor2").val())

Comment: Any luck on this .....


$("#rTpe1").click(function(e){
   $("#rFor1").val((this.value * $("#PerHourRate1").val()).toLocaleString('en-IN'));
  $("#rFor3").val.toLocaleString('en-IN')( Number($("#rFor1").val().replace(/,/g , '')) + Number($("#rFor2").val().replace(/,/g , '')))
});

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve `5,50,500` by using [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). In order to use this, please modify 2 parts as follows.

### 1. HTML

#### From :

```
<input  name="" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" value="0" id="rFor1" readonly>
```

#### To :

```
<input  name="" type="string" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" value="0" id="rFor1" readonly>
```

### 2. Javascript

#### From :

```
$("#rTpe1").click(function(e){
  $("#rFor1").val(this.value * $("#PerHourRate1").val());
});
```

#### To :

```
$("#rTpe1").click(function(e){
  $("#rFor1").val((this.value * $("#PerHourRate1").val()).toLocaleString());
});
```

If `toLocaleString()` cannot be used, please use the following script for Javascript.

```
$("#rTpe1").click(function(e){
  var ar = (this.value * $("#PerHourRate1").val()).toString().split('.');
  $("#rFor1").val(ar[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,') + (ar[1] ? "." + ar[1] : ""));
});
```